# How to add Firebase Analytics as a dependency for a pod?

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I am trying to create an analytics library for my applications. The applications have to go through the framework to send analytics, so Firebase Analytics is a dependency of the pod.

I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/CarlSarkisS/TestPodFA).

When trying to compile the app, the pod does not compile:

> No such module 'Firebase'

If I open the pod framework target build settings and add in the header search path:

> ${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources

The error disappears. Then if I try to use Analytics or Crashlytics, I have the error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "OBJC_CLASS$_FIRAnalytics"

It was not happening with the previous version 6.32.2.

How to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7579

Comment: Yes, I also posted it on the Firebase repo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library's podspec that depends on FirebaseAnalytics should specify `static_framework=true`.

More detail at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7579

Answer (score 0):

I validated the answer from Paul, from Firebase.

To sum up, not to have any issue:

- distribute the pod as static (`static_framework=true`)
- replace `import Firebase` with

```swift
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseCrashlytics // (if required)
```